# Running into issues while deploying multi container instances on Azure using Docker compose

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

`docker compose-up` locally is able to build and bring up the services, but when doing the same on `Azure Container Instances` I get the below error

> containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure
> sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error:
> Code="InaccessibleImage" Message="The image
> 'docker/aci-hostnames-sidecar:1.0' in container group 'djangodeploy'
> is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential."

Also, what is the purpose of this image `docker/aci-hostnames-sidecar`

The ACI deployment was working fine and now suddenly it doesn't work anymore

The `docker-compose.yml` contents are provided below

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  django-gunicorn:
    image: oasisdatacr.azurecr.io/oasis_django:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    command: > 
      sh -c "
      python3 manage.py makemigrations &&
      python3 manage.py migrate &&
      python3 manage.py wait_for_db &&
      python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  celery-worker:
    image: oasisdatacr.azurecr.io/oasis_django_celery_worker:latest
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A oasis worker -l INFO
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - django-gunicorn
  celery-beat:
    image: oasisdatacr.azurecr.io/oasis_django_celery_beat:latest
    build: 
      context: .
    command: celery -A oasis beat -l INFO
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - django-gunicorn
      - celery-worker
```

**UPDATE** There might have been some issue from Azure end as I was able to deploy the containers as I usually do without any changes whatsoever

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a `docker-compose.yml` file that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @DavidMaze `docker-compose.yml` content has been updated on the issue

Answer (score 0):

When you use the docker-compose to deploy multiple containers to ACI, firstly you need to build the images locally, and then you need to push the images to the ACR through the command `docker-compose push`, of course, you need to log in to your ACR first. See the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose).

And if you already push the images to your ACR, then you need to make sure if you log in to your ACR with the right credential and the image name with the tag is absolutely right.

Comment: We were doing the same thing and it was working. But maybe there was some issue from Azure end, because after a while I was able to deploy and bring up my app

Comment: @SubhanKarki As I know, the possible reasons are shown in my answer. If you meet some strange problems else, I only can think about the network. It depends and we can't fix it most time. Well, if it's helpful please accept it.

Comment: @SubhanKarki Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: there was an issue from Azure side, I have no issues now, and haven't had any issues going forward. I had been doing the same thing before facing this issue and I'm doing the same ever since, which did include what you have mentioned. But this was not a solution to the issue I was facing.

Comment: @SubhanKarki Maybe it's the issue on Azure, if so then I can't provide more help.